# How to disable 'totpages' anchor link created by 'hyperref'?

Tags: xetex, hyperref

I've been searching like hell for this, trying to hack the `totpages` and/or the `hyperref` packages but to no avail...

The `totpages` package automatically creates link on every reference to the total number of pages in a document. I'm doing my CV with the `europecv` package and this places a `Page X / TOTAL` on the footer of every page and the `totpages` package automatically creates a link (if `hyperref` is also being used) on `TOTAL` always linking to the last page. This seems a bit pointless to me.

So far I've "disabled" this by setting the border color to white, the link still works, there's just no visual indication that it's a link. But this is not acceptable because this does not allow me to have visual indications on internal links I manually create.

I also tried `\usepackage[anchorpages=false]{hyperref}`, it seems to be the option to disable such linking, but it doesn't work.

Any other solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One needs to patch an internal command of `europecv.cls`. Put the following in your preamble

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ecv@totpages}{\ref}{\ref*}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Alternatively, just rewrite the definition of the command using `\ref*` instead of `\ref`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\ecv@totpages{~/~\ref*{TotPages}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I knew something like this was possible, I should have posted the question sooner. I tried to do it myself but I still consider myself a mediocre LaTeX user.

Comment: @RicardoAmaral Don't worry: we all learn from this site. Surely I've learnt a lot.

Comment: It works for `\pageref*{LastPage}`, too!

Answer (score 5):

Just use `\ref*{TotPages}` instead of `\ref{TotPages}`. Package `hyperref` adds a star form for `\ref` for references without hyperlinks.

Comment: I can't do that as simple as that. I never use `{TotPages}` directly, that's handled by the `europecv` package.